# style parameter not working for print-js when trying to print from vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, printjs

I read it on [print-js documentation](http://printjs.crabbly.com) that we can pass style as a string to `printJS` function, so that style we pass in gets applied, but I a landing to an error that is not allowing the print to happen:

I am getting this error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: style`

I am passing the style to printJS in vue component like this

```
        printSlip: function(){
            printJS('printSlip', 'html', style="display: inline-block; text-align: center; padding: 30px; margin: 15px; text-align: center; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top;");
        },
```

Answer (score 4):

As Husan Ibrahim already answered, to use the `style` parameter, you need to use the object syntax. What Husan missed, is that the `style` parameter is expecting you to target where the style should be applied.

When passing `display: inline-block; text-align: center; padding: 30px; margin: 15px; text-align: center; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top;`, the browser won't know which elements to apply the style.

Let's say you want to apply it to the body, this would be valid `body { display: inline-block; text-align: center; padding: 30px; margin: 15px; text-align: center; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top; }`

Here is an example passing styles to be applied in `my-element1` and `my-element2`:

```js
printSlip() {
    printJS({
        printable: 'printSlip', 
        type: 'html', 
        style: '#my-element1 { color: blue; } #my-element2 { color: red; }'
    })
}
```

Live example passing custom style:
https://codesandbox.io/s/x72j429vr4

Answer (score 1):

Says in the docs that you can pass an object as argument to configure options ..

> Print.js will accept an object as argument, where you can configure
>   some options

```
printSlip: function(){
    printJS({printable: 'printSlip', type: 'html', style: 'display: inline-block; text-align: center; padding: 30px; margin: 15px; text-align: center; padding: 15px; vertical-align: top;'});
},
```

Comment: it did not work for me, though I did not get any error, I am now thinking I am passing the style parameters but to what html tag they will get applied ?